# flutter location , Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK, Background location permission denied forever

Tags: android, flutter, location

I'm using [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) flutter package to access the user's background location, first time any user opens the app it asks for permission, and when the user accepts it brings back this error in the console

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK, Background location permission denied forever - please open app settings, null, null)
```

if the user closed the app and reopened it .. it works perfectly fine ( fetches location in both foreground and background) without even asking again for location permission.

Following the getting started guide in the package itself, here is how I added permission to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue?

Comment: @AhmedElsayed No, too bad I had to force restart the app so in the second time it runs the permission flow goes normally

Comment: Thank you! Have you tried geolocator? Does it have same problem?

Comment: ok, Geolocator has same issue but I've found solution and posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been working on this issue and I discovered that the problem is when you use `location.enableBackgroundMode()` then choose `always` when you hit back first time it throws an exception and `isBackgroundModeEnabled` will be false too "despite the backgroundmode is enabled in system" and you have to restart the app to check if background mode is enabled correctly.

but, I've found that calling `location.enableBackgroundMode()` again is solving the issue too and it really doesn't ask for enabling background again but it somehow make `isBackgroundModeEnabled` return true value. Here's my fix code:

```
Future<bool> enableBackgroundMode() async {
bool _bgModeEnabled = await location.isBackgroundModeEnabled();
if (_bgModeEnabled) {
  return true;
} else {
  try {
    await location.enableBackgroundMode();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
  try {
    _bgModeEnabled = await location.enableBackgroundMode();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
  print(_bgModeEnabled); //True!
  return _bgModeEnabled;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this error by an easy way, i opened the my app settings and go through permissions and i found that the permission fo locations is denied for all time, so i have changed to be allowed all time. and it worked again:)